# Search for keyword in textual file C

Tags: c, file, search, keyword

I'm having trouble reading a keyword from file that a user inputs to search for. The first part of the program asks for user input for naming the file. It then asks for sentence input. You can input sentences until you write "END". When you write "END", the appending of sentences to file should stop and the program should ask you for a keyword to search the sentences appended to the newly created textual file. I used 'gets' to ask for a word that will be searched for in the file. The program should find that word in a sentence and print back the whole sentence containing the keyword. The whole code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char fileName[128];
    printf("Input your filename (end with .txt):");
    gets(fileName);

    FILE *filePointer = NULL;
    char text1[128];
    char word1[128];
    filePointer = fopen(fileName, "a");

    if(filePointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        printf("Input your sentence: ");
        while (fgets(text1, 127, stdin) != NULL && strncmp(text1, "END\n", 5) != 0){
            printf("Input your sentence: ");
            fprintf(filePointer, "%s", text1);
        }

        int line_num = 1;
        int find_result = 0;
        char text2[128];

        filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");

        printf("Input keyword you're looking for: ");
        gets(word1);

        while(fgets(text2, 127, filePointer) != NULL) {
            if((strstr(text2, word1)) != NULL) {
                printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
                printf("\n%s\n", tekst2);
                find_result++;
            }
            line_num++;
        }

        if(find_result == 0) {
            printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
        }

        if(filePointer) {
            fclose(filePointer);
        }

        return(0);
    }
}
```

It all works, but the problem is somewhere here:

```
        int line_num = 1;
        int find_result = 0;
        char text2[128];

        filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");

        printf("Input keyword you're looking for: ");
        gets(word1);

        while(fgets(text2, 127, filePointer) != NULL) {
            if((strstr(text2, rijec)) != NULL) {
                printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
                printf("\n%s\n", text2);
                find_result++;
            }
            line_num++;
        }
```

I'm new at C programming, so I'm not sure where the flaw is. I know it should work in theory. It doesn't return a result when it clearly should.

Comment: You're searching for `rijec` (which is never seen, or set, anywhere else), when the word you're looking for is in `word1`. Also, you'll want to `fclose()` the file after writing, before reopening to read.

Comment: Sorry, that's a residual error. I renamed most the variables for sharing to better understand what every of them are. I'll edit that line...

Comment: @Paul Roub Also, you should post this as an official answer. That was the whole logic I didn't cover; I had to close the file after writing and everything works. I'm such a noob. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I'm aware of the flaws of gets(), it's a educational piece of code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Part of your education needs to be "Do not play with explosives because they're dangerous".  Don't use `gets()` even in practice code because it will escape into production code -- by accident, perhaps, but it will happen.  Remember, the first Internet worm used `gets()` to propagate (that was in 1988; use Google to search for 'morris internet worm').

Comment: @JonathanLeffler He is using fgets, which is a safe and preferable alternative to fscanf when you want a whole line of input. gets is dangerous because it lacks a size parameter.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Unfortunately, my teacher is not aware of this and gives me a hard time for using fgets. I use it in my work all the time.

Comment: @user3662325 Tell your teacher that fgets is safer for reading user input and explain why. You should not be letting your teacher teach students things that the industry knows to be poor methods. In fact, this is such a dangerous thing for a professional to be unaware of, you should talk to your department chair about this since the department should be aware of this incompetence with someone who should know better.

Comment: @user2482551 I changed every gets to fgets and will notify my teacher of his misinterpretation.

Comment: @user2482451: there are several uses of `gets()` as well as several uses of `fgets()`. The only advantage to `gets()` is that it removes the newline. That benefit does not outweigh its disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fclose() the file after writing, before reopening to read.

```
if (fclose(filePointer) != 0)
{
  fputs("The sky is falling.", stderr);
  return 1;
}

filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");
```